Why different references express mass densities as $\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3$ or $1/\mathrm{fm}^3$?
I was reading some papers about equations of state and have found that some of them express the mass density in terms of $\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3$ and others in terms of $1/\mathrm{fm}^3$. Why is this quantity expressed in different units? Is it possible to convert $\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3$ into $1/\mathrm{fm}^3$?

Could you provide some examples? The context in which these expressions are used can be important

Both of them can be used as units of mass density in the context of nuclear or particle physics.

$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$: This is the unit of the energy density (energy per unit volume), often used in nuclear and particle physics, where energies are commonly measured in electron volts ($\mathrm{eV}$) or its multiples ($\mathrm{MeV}$). The femtometre ($1\ \mathrm{fm}=10^{-15}\ \mathrm m$) is a unit of length used at the nuclear or particle scale. In this context, mass and energy are interchangeable due to the fundamental principle of mass-energy equivalence, as described by Einstein's energy equation $E=mc^2$. So, the mass density is often expressed in ${\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$ in this context. Conversion: $1\ \mathrm{MeV}\equiv1.78266192\times10^{-30}\ \mathrm{kg}$
or $1\ \mathrm{MeV}/c^2=1.78266192\times10^{-30}\ \mathrm{kg}$.

$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{1}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$: This unit may represent the rate of interactions or the concentration of particles within a cubic femtometre of space. Each interaction or concentration carries a certain energy. This is particularly relevant when considering phenomena like nuclear reactions or particle collisions. So, expressing the energy or mass density in ${\mathrm{1}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$ is equally valid and meaningful in the context of nuclear or particle physics.


The conversion factor between ${\mathrm{MeV}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$ and ${\mathrm{1}/\mathrm{fm}^3}$ depends on the context (energy associated with the interactions or the concentrations of particles occurring within $1\ \mathrm{fm}^3$ of volume).

thanks for your answer

@johan You're most welcome!
